# Android - AlignParentBottom takes up all the Free Space

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I am trying to align a `button` at the bottom of the layout. But the problem is that whenever I use `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` it takes up all the free space as you can see in the below screeshot.

[image]

**Here is the XML Code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
    tools:context=".Activities.DisplayProductDetails">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/display_ProductImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/material"
        android:layout_below="@+id/display_ProductImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:rotationX="20"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_ProductName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/product_name"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_ProductDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/display_ProductName"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/product_description"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_ProductPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/display_ProductDesc"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/product_price"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                android:id="@+id/enb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/display_ProductPrice"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:backGroundColor="@color/buttonColor"
                app:finalNumber="50"
                app:initialNumber="1"
                app:textColor="#eee" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/display_AddtoCart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/material"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/buttonColor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
        android:textColor="#eee"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line causes aligning top edge of `Button` to bottom edge of `MaterialCardView`

```
android:layout_below="@+id/material"
```

and this line causes aligning bottom edge of `Button` to bottom edge of parent

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

`layout_height="wrap_content"` isn't considered/calculated in this case, as far as I remember it may be even 0px. so everything looks like you designed in XML...

if you want to align button on bottom just use `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and remove `layout_below="@+id/material"` (it will be below anyway)